# Posting image with Swift 2 + AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2, swift2

I have the following code

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.POST(
        "http://shipeala.redmintlabs.com/api/orders/create",
        parameters: params,
        constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData : AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(SHOrderImage.getInstance().image!, name: "photo", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/*")
        },
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
            ""
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
            error: NSError!) -> Void in
            ""
        }
    )
```

And i got this error:

> Cannot invoke 'POST' with an argument list of type '(String, parameters: NSDictionary, constructingBodyWithBlock: (AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// add this line of code for image to NSData conversion
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "yourImageNAme"), 0.5)


let op : AFHTTPRequestOperation = manager.POST("", parameters: parameters, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData!, name: "Photo", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            },
            success:
            {
                (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

                   print(responseObject)                 

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                print(error)

        })!


op.start()
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: well i have added comment in the answer already. that images must be converted to NSData before uploading through Multipart-Form

Comment: This is an instruction not an explanation.

Comment: @MrMush can u help me to answer my asked question, i have asked  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058991/3030400

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this way,

```
        var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        var operation = manager.POST("http://shipeala.redmintlabs.com/api/orders/create", parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "Photo", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
            println(responseObject)
        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
            println(error)
        }

        operation.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. The error was in the first parameter of formData.appendPartWithFileData(), it must be NSData, not UIImage

Comment: In above answer imageData is like   `NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(eachImage,0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the return type "-> Void" of the success handler. This one compiles:

```
    manager.POST("", parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
        //
        }, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        //
        }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        //
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. The error was in the first parameter of formData.appendPartWithFileData(), it must be NSData, not UIImage

Comment: Thats an additional problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Upload image using AFNetworking in Swift 4**

```
func uploadUsingPOST_Image (urlPath: NSString, withParameter dictData: NSMutableDictionary, withImage image: UIImage, WithImageName imageName: NSString,successBlock success:@escaping (_ responceData:AnyObject)->Void) {

    let urlPath1 = "Url path here"

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    var Timestamp: String {
        return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
    }



    let operation =  manager.post(urlPath1 as String, parameters: dictData, constructingBodyWith: { (data:AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in

        let image1: UIImage? = self.resizeImage(image: image, targetSize: CGSize.init(width: 400.0, height: 400.0))

        if image1 != nil {

            data.appendPart(withFileData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1!)!, name: imageName as String, fileName: "\(Timestamp).png", mimeType: "image/png")


        }
    }, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        success(responseObject as AnyObject)
    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
        print(error, terminator: "")
    }

    operation?.start()
}
```