# How do I upload an image using AFNetworking class with Swift 3 in Xcode 8 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift3, afnetworking

```
manager.post(urlString, parameters: perameter, progress: nil,
                     success:
                        {
                            requestOperation, response in
                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (response as! NSData) as Data, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                            self.listData = json["Result"] as! [NSDictionary]
                            print(self.listData)
                            self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()




                        },
                        failure:
                        {
                            requestOperation, error in
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        })
```

Comment: did you use alamofire ?

Comment: can you understand  objective code ?

Comment: i am using only AFNetworking

Comment: And Swift 3 code only i want upload image by post request

Comment: tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33058742/3411787)?

Answer (score 0):

For image upload, you can use multipart.

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = ["text/html"]
    manager.post(url as String, parameters: dic, constructingBodyWith: { (data) in
                if imgData != nil
                {
                    data.appendPart(withFileData: imgData!, name: "image", fileName: imgName as String , mimeType: "image/jpeg")

                }
            }, progress: nil, success: { (sessiondata, result) in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


                let dict = result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(dict)
                if (dict["status"]?.boolValue == true)
                {
                    block(dict as NSDictionary?)
                }
                else{
                    block(dict as NSDictionary?)
                }
            }) { (data, result) -> Void in
                let errorDict = ["error": data?.error?.localizedDescription as AnyObject]

                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                block(errorDict as NSDictionary?)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
            let url = "http://path/to/server"
            let URL : NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
            let req : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    let fileURL = NSURL(string: "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2623.PNG")// change your image url
            manager.POST( url, parameters: nil,
                constructingBodyWithBlock: { (data: AFMultipartFormData!) in
                    do{
                        _ = try data.appendPartWithFileURL(fileURL!, name: "uploaded_file", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }catch{
                    }
                },
                success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                    print("\(responseObject)")
                },
                failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            })
```

Comment: you can upload image through or image data as per your need you can change in this                         _ = try data.appendPartWithFileURL(fileURL!, name: "uploaded_file", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")

Comment: let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourimage, 0.5)                   formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData!, name: "Photo", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

Comment: what is issue faced ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to upload image with other parameter to server:

```
typealias MultipartFormDataBlock = (_ multipartFormData : MultipartFormData?) -> Void
typealias CompletionBlock = (_ response: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

func multiPartRequestWithUrl(url: String, parameters: Dictionary<String,Any>?, multiPartFormDataBlock: MultipartFormDataBlock?, completion: CompletionBlock?) -> Void {
        var param : Dictionary! = parameters ?? Dictionary()
        print("Param = \(param)")
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPartFormData) in
            multiPartFormDataBlock?(multiPartFormData)            
            if param != nil {
                for (key, value) in param! {
                    multiPartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }

        }, to: url, encodingCompletion:{encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        handleResponse(response: value, completion: completion)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        completion?(nil, error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                completion?(nil, encodingError)
            }

        })
    }
```

For New function with AFNetworking

```
+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)multiPartRequestWithURL:(NSString *)strUrl parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))formData progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *progress))progressBlock requestCompletionBlock:(requestCompletionBlock)requestCompletionBlock {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictParameters = [parameters mutableCopy];
    if(!dictParameters) {
        dictParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    dictParameters[@"lang"] = [AppUtility CURRENT_SELECTED_LANGUAGE];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:strUrl parameters:dictParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:formData error:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:3600];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self request:request uploadProgress:^(NSProgress *uploadProgress) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(progressBlock) {
                progressBlock(uploadProgress);
            }
        });
    } downloadProgress:nil requestCompletionBlock:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if(requestCompletionBlock) {
                requestCompletionBlock(responseObject, error);
            }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    return dataTask;
}
```

Comment: I am using only AFNetworking only SWIFT 3 XCODE 8 IOS 10

Comment: See my edited answer. I have added AFNetworking code

Answer (score 0):

**Upload image using AFNetworking in Swift 4**

```
let urlPath1 = "Path url here"

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    var Timestamp: String {
        return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
    }



    let operation =  manager.post(urlPath1 as String, parameters: dictData, constructingBodyWith: { (data:AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in

        if image != nil {

            data.appendPart(withFileData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!, name: imageName as String, fileName: "\(Timestamp).png", mimeType: "image/png")


        }
    }, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        success(responseObject as AnyObject)
    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in

        print(error, terminator: "")
    }

    operation?.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 use following:

```
image.pngData()
```

or

```
forImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
```

based on your requirement.